# Construct a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ such that every point $x\in\Bbb{Q}$ is a local strict minimum point of $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I got this problem:

Construct a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ such that any point $x\in\Bbb{Q}$ is a local **strict** minimum point of $f$

My partial solution:
Define $f$ by $f(x)=1$ if $x\notin\Bbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{p}$ where $0<p\in\Bbb{Z}$ is the unique integer that satisfies $x=\frac{n}{p}$ where $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ and $\text{gcd}(n,p)=1$

Now how can I show that each $x\in\Bbb{Q}$ is a local **strict** minimum of $f$?
Any help will be appreciated.

Note: $f$ has a local strict minimum at $x_0$ means that there exist a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that for all $x$ in this neighborhood $f(x_0)<f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For an $x \in \Bbb Q$, consider the set $I = [x-1/2,x+1/2] \cap [0,\infty)$.  Note that there are finitely many $y \in I$ such that $y \neq x$ and $f(y) \leq f(x)$; enumerate these as $y_1,\dots,y_n$.

We may select a $\delta>0$ such that $\delta < \min_{i=1,\dots,n} \{|x-y_i|\}$.  Let this be the radius of the neighborhood that you consider.

Comment: but can you elaborate a little more on **why** there are finitely many $y\in\Bbb{I}$ such that ......

Comment: What are the $y \in I$ such that $f(y) = 0$?  Such that $f(y) \leq 1 - 1/2$?  Such that $f(y) \leq 1 - 1/3$?  You should notice a pattern emerging.  If it helps, start by thinking specifically about $I = [0,1]$.